XML Spreadsheet Reference - Assign a sheet name from a variable
I am trying to assign a worksheet name from a variable, is this possible
The code I have
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:processing-instruction>

<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

  <Styles>
   
  </Styles>

  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1" >

    <Table>
      <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="60" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
      <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="300" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
      <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
              
      <xsl:call-template name="generateReportData">
        <xsl:with-param name="currentElement" select="$currentElement"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="parentOccurrenceID" select="$parentOccurrenceID"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>

I have tried
<Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">

to
 <Worksheet ss:Name=<Data ss:Type="String">$rootProductID</Data> >

, but no joy
I am using this Reference here
has anyone got some suggestions?
Thanks

global parameter definition area of the style sheet added 11-4-2024, following comments in the question
Also this stylesheet is provided by Siemens and is about to extracted and altered, so to be fair I do not understand the full code and only take copies and alter certain areas
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
           xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
           xmlns:plm="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema"
           xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
           xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
           xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
           xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
           xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" >

  <!-- Note: EMBOM modification to add subsystemgroups/systemgroupstype and makebuy properties -->
  <!--       Author Ian Wheeler 09-04-2024 -->
  
  
  <!-- Define global parameters -->
  <xsl:param name="primaryOccRef" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:ProductView/@primaryOccurrenceRef"/>
  <xsl:param name="rootProductID" select="substring-after(/plm:PLMXML/plm:ProductView/plm:Occurrence[@id=$primaryOccRef]/@instancedRef,'#')"/>
  <xsl:param name="report_date" select="/plm:PLMXML/@date" />

  <!-- Note: the variable below can be set as "display:all" or "display:none" -->
  <!--       to expand all or none internal links at teh report generation" -->
  <xsl:param name="linkDisplayStatus" select="'display:none'"/>

  <!-- Define key functions -->
  <xsl:key name="product"       match="plm:ProductRevision" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:key name="design"        match="plm:DesignRevision" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:key name="part"          match="plm:PartRevision" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:key name="dataset"       match="plm:Dataset" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:key name="form"          match="plm:Form" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:key name="folder"        match="plm:Folder" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:key name="occurrence"    match="plm:Occurrence" use="@id"/>

  <!-- Method for translation -->
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- ******************** -->
  <!-- Header and structure -->
  <!-- ******************** -->
  <xsl:template name="BOMReportHeader">
    <xsl:param name="currentElement"/>
    <xsl:param name="parentOccurrenceID"/>
    <xsl:param name="title"/>
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:processing-instruction>
    
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
        xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
        xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
        xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
        xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

      <Styles>
        <Style ss:ID="heading1">
          <Font ss:Color="#000000" ss:Size="16" ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Bold="1"/>
          <Interior ss:Color="#C0C0C0" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="heading2">
          <Font ss:Color="#000000" ss:Size="12" ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Bold="1"/>
          <Interior ss:Color="#C0C0C0" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="heading3">
          <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left"/>
          <Font ss:Color="#000000" ss:Size="10" ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Bold="1"/>
          <Interior ss:Color="#CCCCFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="cell_data">
          <Font ss:Color="#000000"/>
          <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFCC" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        </Style>
      </Styles>

      <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1" >

        <Table>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="60" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="300" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="300" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="60" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="60" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="150" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="150" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="100" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="150" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="150" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="150" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="200" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="150" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="200" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="200" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="150" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="150" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="500" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          
          <xsl:call-template name="generateReportData">
            <xsl:with-param name="currentElement" select="$currentElement"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="parentOccurrenceID" select="$parentOccurrenceID"/>
          </xsl:call-template>

        </Table>
      </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>

  </xsl:template>


   <!-- **************** Top Level data element **************** -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="topProductId" select="key('product',$rootProductID)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="topDesignId" select="key('design',$rootProductID)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="topPartId" select="key('part',$rootProductID)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$topProductId/@id = $rootProductID" >
         <xsl:call-template name="generateReportPage">
            <xsl:with-param name="currentElement" select="$topProductId"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="parentOccurrenceID" select="''"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$topDesignId/@id = $rootProductID" >
          <xsl:call-template name="generateReportPage">
            <xsl:with-param name="currentElement" select="$topDesignId"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="parentOccurrenceID" select="''"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$topPartId/@id = $rootProductID" >
          <xsl:call-template name="generateReportPage">
            <xsl:with-param name="currentElement" select="$topPartId"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="parentOccurrenceID" select="''"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- *** Create seperate page for each process and to be linked from its parent **** -->
  <xsl:template name="generateReportPage">
    <xsl:param name="currentElement"/>
    <xsl:param name="parentOccurrenceID"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- For the root process, we output to the top level report -->
      <xsl:when test="$rootProductID=$currentElement/@id">
        <xsl:call-template name="BOMReportHeader">
          <xsl:with-param name="currentElement" select="$currentElement"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="parentOccurrenceID" select="$parentOccurrenceID"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'PS(BOM) Report'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ************ generate report data ************* -->
  <xsl:template name="generateReportData">
    <xsl:param name="currentElement"/>
    <xsl:param name="parentOccurrenceID"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="generateCurrentProductData">
      <xsl:with-param name="prtele" select="$currentElement"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="parentID" select="$parentOccurrenceID"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:call-template name="generateChildProduct">
      <xsl:with-param name="currentElement" select="$currentElement"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="parentID" select="$parentOccurrenceID"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ************ generate current product data ************* -->
  Remaining styler sheet here generates content


Please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Michael.hor256k I understand the request  but can not provide all the data enclose as the translation and xml datasets are with our 3rd party PLM system.  I can provide is translation file I am writing but not a dataset or a translation tool

I am afraid I don't understand what you are saying. Do you know what your input XML looks like? You should be able to have a look at it using a stylesheet with only the identity transform template, even if you have no direct access to it. Without this, your chances of writing a correct stylesheet are equal to those of a blind chicken finding a piece of corn. Same thing applies to your stylesheet. What you posted here is not. There are undefined variables and - most importantly - there is no template defining the context.

Hi @michael.hor257k, No you are correct I do not know what my input xml looks like. I do not know how to extract from Siemen Teamcenter PLM the input xml I can post the full style sheet but did not want to overload the question. Would that help?
The actual style sheet works and produces content, my question was just if I could rename the Sheetname

Does the answer by y.arazim not work for you?

Try:
<Worksheet ss:Name="{$rootProductID<}">


Please don't post suggestions to try something. If you post an answer you should be confident it solves the issue. It would be better to check in a comment first.

@GertArnold I believe you are confusing politeness with hesitancy.

It's not that I want to bother you, so let me explain where I come from. From the outset, Stack Overflow's vision was to build a web knowledge base. That means that each Q&A has a far broader scope than just a personal issue that (hopefully) someone helps to solve. The main audience is future visitors. They like to see solutions, not tentative suggestions. Keeping that in mind changes one's answering style.
